# Nexus container exit(1) when run

Tags: docker, nexus

I am trying to run nexus on EC2 ubuntu machine.

```
docker pull sonatype/nexus3

docker run -d -p 8081:8081 --name nexus sonatype/nexus3
```

running containers

```
# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
a0562da202f7        sonatype/nexus3     "sh -c ${SONATYPE_DI…"   7 seconds ago       **Exited (1) 5 seconds ago                       nexus**
#
```

Please do let me know what is going wrong here.

Comment: did you check logs: `docker logs nexus`?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the problem and I face the same as you tried, I resolve this by setting these variables.

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8081:8081 --name nexus -e INSTALL4J_ADD_VM_PARAMS="-Xms2g -Xmx2g -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=3g  -Djava.util.prefs.userRoot=/some-other-dir" sonatype/nexus3
```

Also, you can read the [system requirement](https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/nexus3/)

**Notes**
**Our system requirements should be taken into account when provisioning the Docker container.**

> There is an environment variable that is being used to pass JVM arguments to the startup script
>
> `INSTALL4J_ADD_VM_PARAMS`, passed to the Install4J startup script. Defaults to -`Xms2703m -Xmx2703m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2703m -Djava.util.prefs.userRoot=${NEXUS_DATA}/javaprefs.`

Comment: There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 945094656 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   The process is running with CompressedOops enabled, and the Java Heap may be blocking the growth of the native heap
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2763), pid=25507, tid=0x00007f35a9b77700
#
Looks like I have to upgrade my EC2

Comment: nexus3 container requires a machine with at least 4GB RAM, although for production purposes, a minimum of 8GB RAM is recommended. I tried playing around with the env variables but it still ran out of memory on a 2GB RAM machine.

Comment: So mean you need to upgrade